# Java. Замена по регулярному выражению

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть несколько паттернов, которые я объединяю через `join("|")`.

Задача, каждый паттерн может удовлетворять N-количеству совпадений
Например:  `(и\\s*\\.*\\s*т\\s*\\.?\\s*д\\s*\\.)`
Каждое совпадение забиваем в **`HashMap<String, String>`**, где <Хэш, Совпадение>
Каждое совпадение заменить на хэш в исходной строке.

Проблема: Почему-то `Matcher.find()` делает только одну итерацию цикла и заменяет все паттерны через пайп `|` на один и то же хэш.

Что делать в таком случае, кроме как составлять вручную списки слов?

**UPD**

Упрощенный пример для данной задачи (https://ideone.com/d1UhRh):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main
{
   static void processString(String line)
   {
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(1\\%?|2|3|4)"); // 5 Вариантов паттернов для теста
      Matcher m = p.matcher(line);          // Естественно в реальной задаче намного больше

      HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

      int i = 0;
      while (m.find()) {
        // Здесь я ожидаю 5 итераций для каждого вхождения 1, 1%, 2, 3, 4 и замены их на ААА1, ААА1%, ААА2 и т.д.
        // Эти вхождения добавить в HashMap (map) ниже
        i++;
         System.out.println("Нужно заменить " + m.group() + " на AAA" + i);
         // Добавить $1 в хэшмап !!
         // map.put(?)
         // То есть если я передаю все 5 паттернов, то в map должно быть 5 записей
         line = m.replaceAll("AAA$1");
      }

      System.out.println("\n\n" + line);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      processString(" 1  2  3  4  4  2  1%  1%  1  2  3 ");
   }
}
```

Результат:

> AAA1  AAA1  AAA1  AAA1  AAA1  AAA1  AAA1  AAA1  AAA1  AAA1  AAA1

Ожидаемый результат:

> AAA1  AAA2  AAA3  AAA4  AAA4  AAA2  AAA1%  AAA1%  AAA1  AAA2  AAA3

**UPD 2**
Добавил уточнение по вопросу по поводу HashMap

Comment: Не могли бы Вы привести минимальный пример кода, который нужно усовершенствовать? Если честно, из описания не понял в чем дело.

Comment: @defaultlocale добавил пример

Comment: Может просто использовать `replaceAll("AAA$1")` ?

Comment: @alex окей, как мне тогда в HashMap добавить каждое такое совпадение отдельной записью?

Comment: @Herrgott тогда `while(m.find()) map.put("AAA" + m.group(), m.group());`

Comment: @alex и получается результат первый который тут написан, а нужно еще в hashmap добавлять. Обновил вопрос

Comment: @Herrgott https://ideone.com/N8abmD

Comment: @alex у меня почему-то это не работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поиск производится только один раз потому как [`Matcher.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)) заменяет все вхождения в исходной строке, после чего перезапускает `matcher`:

> This method first resets this matcher. It then scans the input sequence looking for matches of the pattern.

Если нужно заменять вхождения по очереди, то можно воспользоваться [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) и [`Matcher.appendTail`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail(java.lang.StringBuffer)):

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    i++;
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "AAA"+i);
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println("\n\n" + sb);
```

Если нужно сохранять вхождения в `Map`, то можно обрабатывать каждое и запоминать хэши:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {      
    String group = m.group();
    String replacement;
    if(map.containsKey(group)) {
       //уже есть хэш
       replacement = map.get(group);
    } else {
       //создаем  и запоминаем новый хэш
       i++;
       replacement = "AAA"+i;
       map.put(group, replacement);
    }
    m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```

Количество итераций при этом будет равно количеству вхождений, а не количеству уникальных вхождений.

Здесь для удобства используется отображение `Совпадение -> Хэш`, а не `Хэш -> Совпадение` как в вопросе, но при желании можно параллельно вести и обратное отображение.

Добавьте обработку того, что `1` и `1%` сводятся к одному хэшу по вкусу. Либо используйте выражение `(1|2|3|4)`, а проценты оставляйте без изменений.

[Пример на Ideone.](https://ideone.com/ADsDfe)

Comment: Хорошее объяснения. В следующий раз обязательно проверю